# How can I update an Access database in SharePoint from Excel?

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel, sharepoint

I currently have an Access database stored locally. I update this by using Excel as a front-end to input some information and have VBA that inputs records to the database. That is to say, I have a table in Excel that I can add rows to and run a macro that executes some SQL to put it into Access.

I want multiple people to be able to make changes to the Access database, so I have stored it in SharePoint. The problem is that just changing the filepath in my VBA gives me "Operation must use an updateable query" because opening the database is done in read-only mode when you open from SharePoint.

The VBA looks something like this:

```
Sub Insert()
    Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase accDbLocation, True
    theSQL = "insert into Table(data)"
    appAccess.CurrentDb.Execute theSQL
    appAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase
End Sub
```

Is there any good workaround for this? Perhaps a way to check-out the database from SharePoint, make changes, then check it back in? Failing that, are there other ways to interact with an access db on SharePoint, like making a form that could be used to add records?

Thanks!

Comment: "just changing the filepath in my VBA" - what did you change it to?  Did you use a webDAV path ?

Comment: I do not have the SharePoint site mapped to a network drive, if that's what you are asking. It is potentially possible, but it's not ideal since we should ensure that all users have it mapped to the same drive. 

Specifically I changed it to: accDbLocation = "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/allfiles/Shared/Pricing.accdb"

Comment: You don't need to use a mapped drive: you should be able to use a UNC-style path. Something like `\\mysite.sharepoint.com\davwwwroot\allfiles\SharedPricing.accdb`

Comment: Tim: I've tried changing the filepath to "\\mysite.sharepoint.com@ssl/davwwwroot/allfiles/Shared/Pricing.accdb" and it seems to slow everything to a crawl. Excel keeps giving me a "waiting for another application to complete an OLE action" while spinning its wheels.

Comment: Sorry - that's as much as I can offer.  I've done similar things with a non-Sharepoint (but webDAV-enabled) document system and it's worked fine, but that was non-SSL and hosted in-house...

Comment: Tim - I gave it another shot today. It ran very slowly but using the webDAV path let it actually do what I wanted it to do. Thank you for your suggestion!